# Query DOMElement's parent - XPath

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I'm using XPath/PHP to parse HTML of a given URL. Let's say I have the desired node in the DOMElement object `$element`.

How can I perform a query on the parent node of `$element`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/DOMXPath)'s constructor requires you pass it the [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/DOMDocument) of the node:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($element->parentNode->ownerDocument);
$xpath->execute($expression, $element->parentNode);
```